# Applicability of GFN-FF force field and other xTB methods for dynamics of ions in water

Tags: molecular-dynamics, quantum-chemistry, forcefields, water, xtb

I am working on a project involving water clusters with ions in them. One of the problems that I ran into quite early on was that good forcefield parameters are not available for highly charged ions such as $\ce{Al^3+}$, $\ce{Fe^3+}$, $\ce{La^3+}$ (these are the three I am interested in currently).

The [GFN-FF](https://xtb-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gfnff.html) force field claims to be a partially polarizable force field for materials, organometallics and biochemical systems. It claims to provide quantum-chemistry-level accuracy at the cost of a force field calculation. The original [publication](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/anie.202004239) seems to indicate that it can be applied to almost all types of systems. The xTB software also has semi-empirical GFN0, GFN1 and GFN2 methods, which perform QM calculation instead of being classical forcefields.

**Does anyone have any experience using GFN-FF or the other xTB methods for calculations on ion water interactions (or just biological systems containing ions in general)? Do they work well?**

I am worried that there could be problems related to treating the polarization of the water molecules by highly charged ions in GFN-FF (as it calculates the partial charges only once at the start of the calculation). I haven't found any papers that use GFN-FF for molecular dynamics as well. Obviously I could use one of the semi-empirical ones, but it would be very slow for the systems I am working on.

Comment: I interpreted GFN-FF as using charge equilibration, which I further interpret as meaning net charge is constrained but partial charges can vary within a molecule. This means that for an atomic ion, you are really just using a partial (integer) charge that never varies, so I don't see it being "polarizable". Hopefully someone more knowledgeable can clarify this.

Comment: @Wesley Yes, I am worried about the polarization problem mainly. Do you know any other low-cost method/polarizable force field that has parameters for those +3 ions? I have to simulate a nanodroplet with 800 H2O molecules (and the ion).

Comment: I don't but GFN-FF might be good enough for MD. In a water droplet, I would not expect the ion to have an average polarizability(I mean, I expect a spherically symmetric time average), and at least GFN-FF will allow the first and second solvation shells (and others too, they are just less important) to be polarized. For a single snapshot, I would want to use the semi-empirical method, but for MD, I suspect polarizability in the ion is not so important as the shells surrounding it

Comment: I doubt there have been many benchmarks. Besides the Grimme group, I think [our paper on conformer energies](https://doi.org/10.1002/qua.26381) is the only one really testing GFN-FF. If you can't go to a semiempirical method, it's probably the best you can do without generating your own parameters (e.g. for AMOEBA)

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago! I'm surprised this has gone 10+ months without an answer. Did you learn anything more about the problem since then? An update might be helpful!

Comment: Unfortunately not, @NikeDattani !

Comment: I've bumped it up! Maybe you can clarify what you mean by "good parameters are not available" (parameters for a forcefield?) and "which perform the full calculation" (full calculation of what?). Overall, you're just asking for someone who has experience using this method, to tell you how well it worked (presumably by comparing their results with what they would get with the more expensive quantum-chemistry-level calculation)?

Comment: @NikeDattani Yes, I want to know how well it works by comparing to better QM method or experiment. I have clarified the full calculation and parameter part to make it more clear.

Comment: Could you perhaps run (adaptive) QM/MM simulations? For a semi-empirical QM method, MOPAC could be worth a shot, having sparkles for lanthanides.

Comment: I work in this area but have not looked at GFN-FF for this specific question. My guess is that it may perform fine for certain properties, but I doubt it would be quantitative barring some great cancellation of errors. Even polarizable force fields parameterized for highly charged systems struggle to be quantitative, so considering the generic nature of GFN-FF, I find it doubtful that it will quantitatively reproduce binding energies and the like. That being said, it seems worth trying and just seeing how it performs for the quantities of interest.

Comment: As an aside, charge equilibration is known to underestimate polarization energies if one chooses parameters that approximately reproduce the molecular polarizability. This is probably why they call it partially polarizable. You will get no polarization on your cations (which is not a bad approximation but would be for anions). So the performance of the water model itself should probably be a concern. But, again, studying difficult systems and having quantitative force fields are diametrically opposed.